# SSJS Update Query Definition object to "update"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

The intent is to update the TargetUpdateType property of a QueryDefinition object using SSJS. ([reference](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/querydefinition/))

The following SSJS is outputting an error response to the QueryDefinition.Update() function:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var QD_TestAudienceSend_ExternalKey = "qd-testaudiencesend"; 

    var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(QD_TestAudienceSend_ExternalKey);
    var update_status = qd.Update({TargetUpdateType: "update"});

</script>

update_status: <ctrl:var name=update_status />
```

[Code referenced](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, However SSJS is a case-sensitive language so only change you have to do to pass `TargetUpdateType` in `ProperCase` format.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var QD_TestAudienceSend_ExternalKey = "qd-testaudiencesend"; 
    var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(QD_TestAudienceSend_ExternalKey);
    var update_status = qd.Update({TargetUpdateType: "Update"});
</script>


update_status: <ctrl:var name=update_status />
```

**Output:** update_status: OK